# Semi-direct product group proof.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Suppose $\alpha \colon A \to  \operatorname{Aut}(N)$ is a homomorphism and $A_0 \leq A$ is a subgroup.  Prove that $N \rtimes_\alpha A_0$ is a subgroup of $N \rtimes_\alpha A$.  Note that this makes sense because $N \times A_0$ is naturally a subset of $N \times A$.

I'm really having a hard time exactly understanding this problem. Any advice would be helpful. My definition/visualization of a semidirect product group is shaky I think so any help there would be awesome too. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

We need to show that if $(n_1,a_1)$ and $(n_2,a_2)$ are in $N \times A_0$, then 
$$
(n_1,a_1) *_\alpha (n_2,a_2) \in N \times A_0
$$
By definition of the multiplication $*_\alpha$ on $N \rtimes_\alpha A$, we have
$$
(n_1,a_1) *_\alpha (n_2,a_2) = (n_1 \alpha(a_1)(n_2),a_1a_2)
$$
The first element is definitely in $N$.  The second element is in $A_0$ since $A_0$ is a subgroup of $A$.

We also need to show that for every $(n,a)$ in $N\times A_0$, the $*_\alpha$-inverse of $(n,a)$ is in $N\times A_0$.  Let the $*_\alpha$-inverse be called $(n',a')$.  By the definition of $*_\alpha$-multiplication it is clear that $a' = a^{-1}$.  This in in $A_0$ because, again, $A_0$ is a subgroup.
We then need to find $n'$ such that
$$
    n \alpha(a^{-1})(n') = e
$$
Solving,
$$\begin{aligned}
    \alpha(a^{-1})(n') &= n^{-1} \\
\iff \alpha(a)\left(\alpha(a^{-1})(n')\right) &= \alpha(a)\left(n^{-1}\right)\\
\end{aligned}$$
Now $\alpha$ is a homomorphism, so $\alpha(a)\mathbin{\circ}\alpha(b) = \alpha(ab)$.  In particular, 
$$
    \alpha(a)\mathbin{\circ}\alpha(a^{-1}) = \alpha(aa^{-1}) = \alpha(e) = \text{identity function on $N$}
$$
Therefore,
$
    n' =  \alpha(a)\left(n^{-1}\right)
$ and
$$
    (n,a)^{*_\alpha-1} = (\alpha(a)\left(n^{-1}\right),a^{-1}) \in N \times A_0
$$